# Why can't I delete a PDF file on an external hard drive via Mac Terminal?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, terminal

I want to delete a PDF file located on portable hard drive via Terminal (MacOS).
When I tried to remove it with `sudo rm -r`, I got

> override rwxr-xr-x  root/wheel for myfilename.pdf

I typed `y` but got

> rm: myfilename.pdf: Read-only file system

I tried `chmod +w` on this file but nothing changed. I tried `sudo rm -rf` on this file, Terminal asked me for password, and then I got the same message `rm: myfilename.pdf: Read-only file system`.

Why can't I delete this file?

Comment: What format is the drive?

Comment: Now I see where the problem is, because the drive has the NTFS format. Thanks a lot.